# Not able to use map() or select(range()) with Huggingface Dataset library, gives dill_.dill has no attribute log

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface, dill, huggingface-datasets

I'm not able to do dataset.map() or dataset.select(range(10)) with huggingface Datasets library in colab. It says `dill_.dill has no attribute log`
I have tried with different dill versions, but no luck.
I tried with older versions of dill lib but they were also giving same error.
Is there a way to fix the issue? Or, any work around?
Any leads will be helpful

stack trace:

```html
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-dd9b972a8f3f> in <module>
      1 test_data = load_dataset("scientific_papers", "arxiv", ignore_verifications=True, split="test")
      2 print(test_data)
----> 3 data = test_data.select(range(10))

16 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    155         }
    156         # apply actual function
--> 157         out: Union["Dataset", "DatasetDict"] = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    158         datasets: List["Dataset"] = list(out.values()) if isinstance(out, dict) else [out]
    159         # re-apply format to the output

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/datasets/fingerprint.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    155                     if kwargs.get(fingerprint_name) is None:
    156                         kwargs_for_fingerprint["fingerprint_name"] = fingerprint_name
--> 157                         kwargs[fingerprint_name] = update_fingerprint(
    158                             self._fingerprint, transform, kwargs_for_fingerprint
    159                         )

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/datasets/fingerprint.py in update_fingerprint(fingerprint, transform, transform_args)
    103     for key in sorted(transform_args):
    104         hasher.update(key)
--> 105         hasher.update(transform_args[key])
    106     return hasher.hexdigest()
    107 

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/datasets/fingerprint.py in update(self, value)
     55     def update(self, value):
     56         self.m.update(f"=={type(value)}==".encode("utf8"))
---> 57         self.m.update(self.hash(value).encode("utf-8"))
     58 
     59     def hexdigest(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/datasets/fingerprint.py in hash(cls, value)
     51             return cls.dispatch[type(value)](cls, value)
     52         else:
---> 53             return cls.hash_default(value)
     54 
     55     def update(self, value):

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/datasets/fingerprint.py in hash_default(cls, value)
     44     @classmethod
     45     def hash_default(cls, value):
---> 46         return cls.hash_bytes(dumps(value))
     47 
     48     @classmethod

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/datasets/utils/py_utils.py in dumps(obj)
    387     file = StringIO()
    388     with _no_cache_fields(obj):
--> 389         dump(obj, file)
    390     return file.getvalue()
    391 

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/datasets/utils/py_utils.py in dump(obj, file)
    359 def dump(obj, file):
    360     """pickle an object to a file"""
--> 361     Pickler(file, recurse=True).dump(obj)
    362     return
    363 

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/dill/_dill.py in dump(self, obj)
    392         f = filename
    393     else:
--> 394         f = open(filename, 'wb')
    395     try:
    396         if byref:

/usr/lib/python3.9/pickle.py in dump(self, obj)
    485         if self.proto >= 4:
    486             self.framer.start_framing()
--> 487         self.save(obj)
    488         self.write(STOP)
    489         self.framer.end_framing()

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/dill/_dill.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    386 def dump_session(filename='/tmp/session.pkl', main=None, byref=False, **kwds):
    387     """pickle the current state of __main__ to a file"""
--> 388     from .settings import settings
    389     protocol = settings['protocol']
    390     if main is None: main = _main_module

/usr/lib/python3.9/pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    558             f = self.dispatch.get(t)
    559             if f is not None:
--> 560                 f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self
    561                 return
    562 

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/dill/_dill.py in save_singleton(pickler, obj)
   1524 def pickles(obj,exact=False,safe=False,**kwds):
   1525     """
-> 1526     Quick check if object pickles with dill.
   1527 
   1528     If *exact=True* then an equality test is done to check if the reconstructed

/usr/lib/python3.9/pickle.py in save_reduce(self, func, args, state, listitems, dictitems, state_setter, obj)
    689             write(NEWOBJ)
    690         else:
--> 691             save(func)
    692             save(args)
    693             write(REDUCE)

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/dill/_dill.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    386 def dump_session(filename='/tmp/session.pkl', main=None, byref=False, **kwds):
    387     """pickle the current state of __main__ to a file"""
--> 388     from .settings import settings
    389     protocol = settings['protocol']
    390     if main is None: main = _main_module

/usr/lib/python3.9/pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    558             f = self.dispatch.get(t)
    559             if f is not None:
--> 560                 f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self
    561                 return
    562 

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/datasets/utils/py_utils.py in save_function(pickler, obj)
    583         dill._dill.log.info("# F1")
    584     else:
--> 585         dill._dill.log.info("F2: %s" % obj)
    586         name = getattr(obj, "__qualname__", getattr(obj, "__name__", None))
    587         dill._dill.StockPickler.save_global(pickler, obj, name=name)

AttributeError: module 'dill._dill' has no attribute 'log
```

Comment: I'm the `dill` author.  How old of a version of `dill` did you use? If you use an old enough version, there should be a `log.info` found.  I think that change was made in July 2022 in https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/commit/38d2a9508ce285a358e3d4e144dc5a9a3c7f2f10.  Feel free to submit a GitHub issue on `dill`.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns Thanks for the quick reply. I raised the issue yesterday and got the solution for the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I raised the Github issue on dill.
They suggested to do `pip install -U datasets`

Pls look at the issue [here](https://github.com/huggingface/datasets/issues/5645)

Comment: Added an alias `log = logger` which should fix https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/582